# Selenium Actions click() method is not working

Tags: selenium

I am using `Firefox Quantum` 63.0.1 (64 bit) with `Selenium 3.14`. I can use the following code to click on a drop down list and it works fine.

```
        WebElement elementToClickAndHold= driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#eventTypeInd"));
        elementToClickAndHold.click();
```

But the following code does not work.

```
        WebElement elementToClickAndHold= driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#eventTypeInd"));
        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        builder.click(elementToClickAndHold);
```

Obviously I could just use the `WebElement.click()` method but I need to use some of the `Actions` methods for other issues so I need to figure out why the `Actions` methods are not working.

The `html` for the drop down list is:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 text-right">
        <span class="required">*</span><label for="eventTypeInd" >Type of Event:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 text-left">
        <select name="eventTypeInd" tabindex="1" onchange="dirtyFlag()" id="eventTypeInd"><option value=""></option>
            <option value="B">Bypass</option>
            <option value="S">SSO (Overflow)</option></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

The meta data for the html page is

```
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" /> 
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"  />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

Comment: There's a lot more to the builder class than just one method.  You need to do more than list one (or more steps) to the builder.  You need to build it and/or perform it.  Read up on the actions class and look for some examples.

Comment: Thanks! I went back and looked at the example I had used and saw what you meant.